# vue.js smooth scroll to middle, bottom and back top top with arrow keys

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I would like to use the up and down arrow keys to smoothscroll down and up the page.

The **first** down keypress should take me to the middle (50%),
 the **second** down keypress to the bottom of the page 
and vice versa with the up key.

Is this possible with vue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible with pure javascript, hence also possible with vue

**Have a look at [this example](https://codepen.io/vanechka222/pen/jOwybdm?editors=1010)**

First, pay attention to this method:

```
    scrollView(amount) {
      let scrollFromTop = window.pageYOffset;
      const viewHeight = Math.round(window.innerHeight * Math.abs(amount));
      if (scrollFromTop % viewHeight === 0) scrollFromTop += Math.sign(amount);
      let targetPos;
      if (amount > 0)
        targetPos = Math.ceil(scrollFromTop / viewHeight) * viewHeight;
      else
        targetPos = Math.floor(scrollFromTop / viewHeight) * viewHeight;
      window.scrollTo({
        top: targetPos,
        behavior: "smooth"
      });
    }
```

It determines view height and current scroll from top. Then, it scrolls the page up or down based on provided amount and in relation with view size.

NB: smooth scrolling is not yet supported in some browsers, you should use [smoothscroll-polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/smoothscroll-polyfill), if you decide to implement this solution.

Next have a look at these couple of hooks responsible for key event listening:

```
  mounted() {
    window.addEventListener("keydown", this.keyHandler);
  },
  beforeUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("keydown", this.keyHandler);
  }
```

And last but not least, event handling logic:

```
    keyHandler(e) {
      if (e.key === 'ArrowDown') {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.scrollView(this.scrollAmount); 
      }
      if (e.key === 'ArrowUp') {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.scrollView(this.scrollAmount * -1); 
      }
    },
```

Comment: @Tarik if it solved your problem, care to accept the answer?

Comment: sorry for the delay @vch

Answer (score 1):

This should be possible with `vue.js` and/or some `JavaScript`. If you want to bind this actions to some `html` elements, you should take a look at [KeyCode Modifiers](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/keycode-modifiers.html#_3-x-syntax), where you have the option to bind them on `v-on`. If you just want to use some `JavaScript` without binding the actions to `vue.js`, it could be something like this:

```
document.onkeydown = keyDownFunc;

function keyDownFunc(e) {
    e = e || window.event;

    if (e.keyCode == '40') {
        // do something
    }
}
```

In this case `40` is `arrow down`. To get your key codes just visit: [keycode.info](https://keycode.info/).

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort  